# Distributed simulation of synchronous Modelica model via sockets

Tags: sockets, modelica

I am looking for a practical way to achieve distributed simulation of a synchronous submodel from a Modelica model via sockets. To make this more concrete, let's consider the library example Modelica_Synchronous.Examples.SimpleControlledDrive.ClockedWithDiscreteController. I would like to execute the code of the feedback controller (assuming it would be packaged as a submodel) remotely.

The only way I see is to export the source code of the feedback controller submodel and manually wrap it in a socket communication interface. Then in Modelica the submodel would be replaced by a corresponding socket wrapper as well, e.g. using an approach similar as the one described [here](http://blog.kempj.co.uk/2013/12/modelica-socket-communication-part-1-socket-library/).

Are there other (ideally simpler) ways to achieve this? Pointers are welcome.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are hoping to achieve.  Do you want to run lots of these in parallel to represent different parts of a controller, do you want to run in real-time?  What are your target platforms, etc?

Comment: I would like to use it for rapid prototyping. The idea is to use the generated controller code on a remote platform. The socket communication would allow me to leave the controller more or less unchanged regardless of whether it operates in feedback with the model or the actual plant. The target platform is essentially a PC-like environment.

Comment: Well, I might have a proprietary solution for you.  But I suspect that isn't what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for the offer but I am just using it in a toy application. Basically I would like to know if the approach I sketched is a good one or if there are better ones.